# What happens to my firebase project if the google account is disabled

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have multiple firebase projects with Google Cloud, Firestore, and Google API integrations set up through my google account run by my company. They are migrating the whole company over to Microsoft and that includes shutting down all Google accounts. If this goes through, what will happen to the Firebase projects attached to that google account? It is my understanding that you need a Google account to have a firebase project at all. I am trying to convince them to spare shutting down my google account but since I don't know exactly what the ramifications would be, that has been difficult.

I have looked around online and through the Google FAQs but nothing seems to answer what would happen to things like all the data in my firestore database or cloud functions. I suspect one way or another I will need a google account but I need to know if all that will be erased if the existing google accounts are shut down.

Answer (score 1):

Any Firebase project is also a Google Cloud project, it just has some extra features enabled on it. So if you delete the Google account that owns that project (or it gets disabled), the associated Cloud and Firebase resources will also be disabled. You will need to continue to have a Google account to use those resouces.